# ionic 2 navigation does not work with arguements

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have gotten a link to work without trying to access its arguments:

```
//home.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {FishPage} from '../fish';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [FishPage]
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private goFish: FishPage,) {
       this.goFish = FishPage;
  }

  playPoker(){
    this.navCtrl.push(FishPage, {
        drag: 'ichabod'
    });
  }

}
```

The link works until I add code to `FishPage` to access the passed in information.  Here is FishPage:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'fish.html'
})
export class FishPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    let param = this.navParams.get('drag');
  }
}
```

For some reason, the code returns this error:

> [14:18:36]  Error: src/pages/home/home.ts(16,4): error TS2322: Type
>   'typeof FishPage' is not assignable to type 'FishPage'.   Property
>   'navCtrl' is missing in type 'typeof FishPage'

Comment: Remove fishpage from providers. Providers are meant to have services

Comment: ^^ and since you're using ionic 2 RC0 (since you're working in `src`) change the `private` keyword in the constructor to `public`. (why is it in your constructor btw?)